# QLikVIew reference to a Calculated Dimension in another Calculated Dimension

Tags: charts, reference, scripting, qlikview

Is it possible to refer to a Calculated Dimension in another Calculated Dimension in a Pivot Table ? Can ValueList() be used for this usage, and what would be the appropriate syntax for it ?

I cannot use the script for this, and I cannot create a new variable either.

I cannot copy the whole expression for the first calculated dimension in the expression for the second calculated dimension as both expression are very expensive (pick(match(...)).

Thanks

Comment: You cannot reference a dimension value but you can use the same expression. Valulist() is a good idea if you need a synthetical dimension..

Comment: the expression is a very long pick(match(...)), I doubt I can succeed copying it in the second dimension ...

Comment: Why not? Copy / Paste ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no obvious way to refer to other calculated dimensions in other calculated dimensions. As you mention that you are restricted to creating an expression solution only, then my other suggestion of using a variable is not applicable in this case.

Therefore it appears that you have to repeat the calculated dimension.

I would say that if you truly have to use an expression solution then it may be worth trying to optimise your calculated dimension as much as possible so that when you have to repeat it in your document it should have a negligible extra impact on performance.

`ValueList` is useful for generating dimension values, but I do not think it could help you here as you still cannot refer to other calculated dimensions using it. It is really designed for generating values for calculated dimensions, and has the following syntax:

```
ValueList(value {, value })
```

So for example, I could use:

```
=ValueList('Category A','Category B','Category C')
```

If I put it into a Pivot Table chart, I would obtain:

[image: QlikView Table demonstration of ValueList]

As you can see, the value of your expression is repeated for each entry provided by ValueList. However, ValueList has a nice trick up its sleeve which means that you can also use it in an expression to display different values depending on the dimension value it appears against.

So for example, if I used the following as my table's expression:

```
=if(ValueList('Category A','Category B','Category C')='Category A',
    sum(Value * 10),
    if(ValueList('Category A','Category B','Category C')='Category B',
        sum(Value * 100),
        sum(Value * 1000)
      )
    )
```

Here you can see that I added a test to see if we were in "Category A" and then displayed the value `sum(Value * 10)` and then for "Category B", `sum(Value * 100)` and so on, this results in:

[image: QlikView Table demonstration of ValueList in the expression]

Comment: What is Value ? in your example.. I tried replicating this and typed =sum(Value) as an expression and it said that it does not recognizes value...

Comment: `Value` is the name of the field that you wish to sum, e.g. `SalesValue`